# play scala reads for Map[Int,List[String]] with exeptions

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I'm using Scala and Play framework. So I have a structure that is **Map[Int, List[String]]** and I need to define a formatter for that. I also need not only to parse keys as Ints, but get en error if one of the keys wasn't parsed succesfully. Here's what I've tried to code, but apperently it doesn't work.

```
def mapReads: Reads[Map[Int, List[String]] = new Reads[Map[Int, List[String]] {
def reads(myJs: JsValue): JsResult[Map[Int, List[String]] =
    (myJs.as[Map[String, List[String]].map{case (k, v) =>
        Integer.parseInt(k) -> v
    }).map(JsSuccess(_)).getOrElse(JsError("Key was not Integer"))
}
```

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: can you post some reproducible data to test your functions and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: This is not a `Reads`. You are just using existing `Reads` which are implicitly available in `myJs.as[Map[String, List[String]]`. And since you are trying `Integer.parseInt(k)` on keys, its obvious that you get an error if any of the keys is not a valid `Int`

Comment: @Daniella : did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val mapReads: Reads[Map[Int, List[String]]] = new Reads[Map[Int, List[String]]] {
    def reads(jv: JsValue): JsResult[Map[Int, List[String]]] =
        JsSuccess(jv.as[Map[String, List[String]]]
                    .map{
                        case (k, v:List[String]) => Integer.parseInt(k) -> v
                     })
}
```

Try it out:

```
val json = Json.parse("""{ "1": ["one", "two"] }""")

println(json.validate[Map[Int, List[String]]])
```